# How to exclude a Test package from running in parallel JUNIT 5?

Tags: java, testing, junit, parallel-execution

I am using the new feature of junit 5 for parallel execution and i want to exclude a Controller folder where all the classes use mockMvc( not safe thread ) for testing sequentially . So i tried to use surefire but it's not working . SO is there any solution with junit 5 jupiter to exclude some packages from running in parallel . 
I use junit-plateform.properties :

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=dynamic
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=8
```

Comment: have you find any solution?